# PHPExcel reader doesn't seem to be reading in file?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to open an xlsx file to parse it into an sqlite3 db. But I don't seem to be able to even open the xlsx file.

This is my code:

```
<?php

  require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
  require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  print "trying to upload";

  $fileName = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
  $target_path = "someDir/";
  $target_path .= $fileName;

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
  {
    print "Upload Successful";  
    chmod($fileName, 0644);

    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007(); 
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

    print "still online!";
  }
?>
```

but the script doesn't make it to the last print statement. So somewhere things are getting messed up in those 4 calls to the PHPExcel API. But no errors are reported.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Is your script running out of memory? PHPExcel can consume large amounts of memory if your spreadsheet is large.

Comment: Why do you create a `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();` and then overwrite this `$objPHPExcel`?

Comment: @Niels the new PHPExcel() is a typo from a previous test (forgot to comment it out, sorry). @Sjoerd About error reporting, do I need to set anything else besides `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ? I'm new to PHP so I guess I might be missing something else for error reporting? And about memory in general, all I can say is that the exact same code worked with excel_reader_2

Comment: and just in case, I'm doing the file upload in another php file and it does work and the file uploads just fine and $fileName does point to a valid file.

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz The best way to get all errors displayed at runtime is `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors',1);`. I suspect if you do this you will see an error message you didn't previously get.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to load the file relative to the script path, but you've actually moved it to another directory.  So change this line:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);
```

to:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($target_path);
```

which would be the full path, eg, 'someDir/filename.xlsx'.

You'll want to change your chmod call to use $target_path as well, as it's unlikely it is finding the file to modify the permissions (it'll just return false if not).